# How to dismiss PKToolPicker when view disappears in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui, pencilkit

I'm trying to wrap `PKCanvasView` as a SwiftUI view called `CanvasView`. I'd like to be able to toggle the whole canvas on top of another view. When the `CanvasView` appears, I'd like the `PKToolPicker` to appear. When it disappears, I'd like the `PKToolPicker` to disappear.

I've found a few similar approaches on here but they only involve showing the picker or toggling the picker with a button; I'd like the picker visibility to be tied to the view visibility.

In the below example you can see that you can toggle the canvas, but once the tool picker is visible, it stays visible.

Here's my `CanvasView`:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PencilKit

struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PKCanvasViewDelegate {
        var canvasView: Binding<PKCanvasView>
        let onChange: () -> Void

        init(canvasView: Binding<PKCanvasView>, onChange: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.canvasView = canvasView
            self.onChange = onChange
        }

        func canvasViewDrawingDidChange(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
            if canvasView.drawing.bounds.isEmpty == false {
                onChange()
            }
        }
    }

    @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    @Binding var toolPickerIsActive: Bool
    private let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()

    let onChange: () -> Void

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear
        canvasView.isOpaque = true
        canvasView.delegate = context.coordinator
        showToolPicker()

        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        toolPicker.setVisible(toolPickerIsActive, forFirstResponder: uiView)
    }

    func showToolPicker() {
      toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
      toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
      canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(canvasView: $canvasView, onChange: onChange)
    }
}
```

And an example `ContentView`:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var canvasView = PKCanvasView()
    @State private var toolPickerIsActive = false
    @State private var canvasIsVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if canvasIsVisible {
                CanvasView(canvasView: $canvasView,
                           toolPickerIsActive: $toolPickerIsActive,
                           onChange: canvasDidChange)
                    .onAppear { toolPickerIsActive = true }
                    .onDisappear { toolPickerIsActive = false }
            }

            Button(action: {
                canvasIsVisible.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Toggle canvas view")
            })
        }
    }

    private func canvasDidChange() {
        // Do something with updated canvas.
    }
}
```

Any guidance would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your scenario the `CanvasView` is destroyed on disappear, so SwiftUI rendering engine just not update it on any state change (as it see that no needs for that).

The possible solution for this use-case is to hide picker on coordinator `deinit` (because it is destroyed with owner view).

Here is a demo. Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

[image: demo]

```
struct CanvasView: UIViewRepresentable {

    class Coordinator: NSObject, PKCanvasViewDelegate {
        var canvasView: Binding<PKCanvasView>
        let onChange: () -> Void
        private let toolPicker: PKToolPicker

        deinit {       // << here !!
            toolPicker.setVisible(false, forFirstResponder: canvasView.wrappedValue)
            toolPicker.removeObserver(canvasView.wrappedValue)
        }

        init(canvasView: Binding<PKCanvasView>, toolPicker: PKToolPicker, onChange: @escaping () -> Void) {
            self.canvasView = canvasView
            self.onChange = onChange
            self.toolPicker = toolPicker
        }

        func canvasViewDrawingDidChange(_ canvasView: PKCanvasView) {
            if canvasView.drawing.bounds.isEmpty == false {
                onChange()
            }
        }
    }

    @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    @Binding var toolPickerIsActive: Bool
    private let toolPicker = PKToolPicker()

    let onChange: () -> Void

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear
        canvasView.isOpaque = true
        canvasView.delegate = context.coordinator
        showToolPicker()

        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        toolPicker.setVisible(toolPickerIsActive, forFirstResponder: uiView)
    }

    func showToolPicker() {
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
        toolPicker.addObserver(canvasView)
        canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }

    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator(canvasView: $canvasView, toolPicker: toolPicker, onChange: onChange)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var canvasView = PKCanvasView()
    @State private var toolPickerIsActive = false
    @State private var canvasIsVisible = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            if canvasIsVisible {
                CanvasView(canvasView: $canvasView,
                              toolPickerIsActive: $toolPickerIsActive,
                              onChange: canvasDidChange)
                    .onAppear { toolPickerIsActive = true }
//                    .onDisappear { toolPickerIsActive = false }
            }

            Button(action: {
                canvasIsVisible.toggle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Toggle canvas view")
            })
        }
    }

    private func canvasDidChange() {
        // Do something with updated canvas.
    }
}
```

Note: there might be redesign of ownership, so `toolPicker` will live only within coordinator, but it does not change idea, and is up to you.

Comment: Is the only way of using **PencilKit** is through **UIViewRepresentable** like you did? can we do the same just with pure SwiftUI and not using UIViewRepresentable?

Comment: @swiftPunk, PencilKit is UIKit based framework

Comment: Excellent thanks @Asperi. Btw I'm doing a lot of SwiftUI googling recently and your answers often appear and are always very valuable and useful, so thank you!

Comment: I got this error: `Modifications to the layout engine must not be performed from a background thread after it has been accessed from the main thread`

Comment: @Asperi For some reason if you set canvasIsVisible to true by default, the pen mode breaks and it always draw in black line

Comment: This didn't work for me. The PKToolPicker still shows sometimes.